# getting warning in Realm at app archive time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I'm using Realm 5.3.3.
I'm getting bellow 2 warning in Xcode at the time of achieving of my app in app store

**Direct access in function 'auto realm::sync::Instruction::visit<(anonymous namespace)::RecoverLocalChangesetsHandler&>((anonymous namespace)::RecoverLocalChangesetsHandler&)' from file '/Users/ripasaha/project/Pods/Realm/core/librealmcore-ios.a(client_reset.o)' to global weak symbol 'typeinfo for realm::Lstrealm::Timestamp' from file '/Users/ripasaha/project/Pods/Realm/core/librealmcore-ios.a(list.o)' means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.**

second warning is below:-

**/Users/ripasaha/project/Pods/Realm/Realm/RLMObjectBase.mm:317:31: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'int64_t' (aka 'long long') to 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')**

But the app is suceccfully uploaded to app store.

But 1 point I noticed that - in app store "INVITES, INSTALLS, CRASHES, FEEDBACK"
-- under all this point , no count is showing.
[image: app store]

please see - build 6 & 7. I've got the above warning for this 2 builds.
And here no invites count showing. But still - everybody is getting invitation for testing.

Any help please to fix this...

Comment: Showing us errors isn't very helpful. We need to understand the context of the error  and the seeing the code that's causing the error is pretty much a requirement. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to ignore them until someone fix the conversion issues in the `Realm` source code if it is not in your own class.

To get rid of warnings you might want to set `No` to `Implicit Conversion to 32 Bit Type` in `project build settings`

About count update on appstore, i am not sure but if someone installs and runs the app it is supposed to update. You might have tried refreshing page already though but not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Realm & RealmSwift 5.3.6 has fixed it, at least for me, try a 'Pod update'

Comment: Nop... they did realesed Realm 5.4.0 and still the same warnings.
these warnings only appear while testing on real device...